# Отправка строки из html страницы в БД через php

Tags: php

функция действует по onclick-у. проверял через alert

помогите с php кодом которые эти данные будет принимать и отправлять в БД

```
function SaveMenu() {
  var tab = document.getElementById("AddNewTable");
  var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var Stroka = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    strID = elems[i].id;
    if (strID.substr(0, 5) == 'EdIzm') {
      Stroka = Stroka + strID.substr(5) + "|";
      Stroka = Stroka + elems[i].value + "|";
      Stroka = Stroka + document.getElementById("EdCost" + strID.substr(5)).value + "|";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `данные которые я выбрал или записал, сохраняются` - а куда записал и куда сохраняются?

Comment: моя ошибочка, извиняюсь. функция на onclick, alert-ом проверял.

Comment: Прочитайте про `XMLHttpRequest` и вопросы отпадут.

Comment: У вас переменная `strID` - глобальная. Допишите `var`, если это не было запланировано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Отправка данных на сервер

Данные на сервер могут быть отправлены тремя способами:

- по ссылке - get-запрос, данные в query string, открывается новая(target) либо перезагружается текущая страница.
- формой - get/post запрос, данные в полях формы
  Страница обновляется либо открывается новая, если указан `target`.
  В качестве `target` может быть указан `iframe`, возможно скрытый.
- AJAX - инициируется из javascript, ответ приходит тоже в javascript.
  Обновления страницы не происходит.

#### Ajax

Ajax-запрос можно осуществить несколькими способами.
Самый распространённый - использование класса `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/api/script.php');
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
var body = [
  'name=' + encodeURIComponent('Alice'),
  'age=' + encodeURIComponent('22'),
].join('&');

xmlhttp.send(body);
```

Популярные библиотеки, такие как `jQuery` имеют свои удобные обёртки для `ajax` запросов: [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

---

Пример с современным [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
*Он очень удобен, но имеет [некоторые проблемы](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) с поддержкой браузерами (IE, Safari...).

По счастью, реализовать [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) не очень сложно.*

```js
function save() {
  var endpoint = 'http://httpbin.org/post';
  var Stroka = 'g/ml|13.5|15';
  fetch(endpoint, {  
    method: 'post',  
    headers: {  
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
    },  
    body: 'data='+encodeURIComponent(Stroka)
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
}

save();
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что вы уже получили данные в php, и вам нужно эти данные сохранить в базу данных.
Так как в вопросе не указана используемая база данных, будем считать, что используется [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Общение php с базами данных осуществляется посредством драйверов реализованных в виде расширений.

Для mysql могут использоваться 2 различных драйвера:

- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.overview.php)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.pdo.php)

Рассмотрим сохранение данных на примере `PDO`.

В первую очередь нужно установить соединение с базой:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Теперь осталось лишь сохранить нужные данные:
*Предположим, что у вас есть таблица `Storage` с текстовой колонкой `data`*

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Storage (data) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->execute([$_POST['data']]);
```